# Make python3 program press "enter" multiple times

Tags: python, linux, openvpn

I use OpenVPN at my company and am trying to automate user creation process. There's a problem at the certificate generation step I faced now. When trying to build a key for the user (all parameters are predefined) program has to press Enter multiple times and in the end "y" and "Enter" 2 times. I tried using Popen and PIPE, but no luck so far. Would appreciate any insight.

```
import sys, os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
# Generate an .ovpn file

try:
    username = sys.argv[1]
except:
    print "Error. Supply a username!"
    sys.exit()

print("Adding user")
os.system("useradd" + " -m" + " -s" + " /bin/bash" + username)
print("Sourcing vars")
os.system('source + /home/myuser/openvpn-ca/vars')
enter = Popen(['/home/myuser/openvpn-ca/build-key {}'.format(username)]), 
stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
enter.communicate(input='\n')
```

Edit:

This is different than what it was marked [duplicate] for. Here's why:

I don't need to generate a custom certificate, change any values etc. It just needs to press "Enter" multiple times and input "yes" and "Enter" 2 times.

Comment: Haven't tried this myself, but what happens if you put `time.sleep(x)` in between `enter.communicate(input='\n')`s, where `x` is a number of seconds to sleep?

Comment: It raises an error. ./pkitool not found, /home/myuser/whichopensslcnf: not found. 
Also, subprocess raises errors in communicate and _stdin_write.

Comment: Your code only supplies a single newline, what happens if you put two? This is probably a duplicate of another question, though at this time I am reluctant to reopen it more because it is unclear. Can you please [edit] your question to indicate what happens if you put two newlines, with a pause between them if the client program requires it?

Comment: It returns:

./pkitool: 293: can't shift that many
waits for the amount of time I provided and the exits

Comment: Seems vaguely unrelated: https://askubuntu.com/questions/812299/error-building-openvpn-key

Comment: Shouldn't you have a space after `/bin/bash`?

Comment: @tripleee Key-building is fine. I do it manually often enough. That's exactly why I want to write this code to do the job for me. 

Adding user works fine, the build-key part is the one I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `source` a shell script from Python; or rather, you can, but it will simply start a new subprocess which `sources` something and then disappears, without changing anything in your Python environment or subsequent subprocesses.

Try something like this instead:

```
import sys
import logging   # to get diagnostics on standard error instead
import subprocess

# Maybe switch to level=logging.WARNING once you are confident this works
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(module)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s')

try:
    username = sys.argv[1]
except:
    logging.error("Error. Supply a username!")
    sys.exit()

logging.info("Adding user")
subprocess.run(["useradd", "-m", "-s", "/bin/bash", username],
    check=True, universal_newlines=True)
logging.info("Building key")
subprocess.run('''
        source /home/myuser/openvpn-ca/vars
        /home/myuser/openvpn-ca/build-key {}'''.format(username),
    shell=True, check=True, input='\n\n', universal_newlines=True)
```

The switch to `subprocess.run()` requires a reasonably new version of Python 3.  In older versions, `subprocess.check_call()` would do roughly the same thing, but didn't have an `input=` argument, so you really did have to use the basic `Popen()` for this.

Additional notes:

- The plus sign after `source` was obviously a syntax error
- We use `check=True` throughout to make sure Python checks that the commands finish successfully.
- Mixing `os.system()` with `subprocess` is not an error, but certainly a suspicious code smell.

(Much) more about using `subprocess` on U*x here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've never thought about using subprocess before. 
I can't see the part of pressing "Enter" multiple times on signing certificate prompt. That's the piece of code I'm curious about.

Comment: `input='\n\n'` passes two newlines as standard input to the subprocess. If it doesn't blindly accept stdin, you need something like `pexpect`.